# Infinispan in wildFly 13

Tags: java, hibernate, wildfly, infinispan

Using WildFly 13, hibernate 5.3.1 Final where I`m trying to setup infinispan as the cache provider.
Hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<session-factory name="java:jboss/HibernateFactory">

    <!-- Second-level caching -->
    <property name="SecondLevelCacheEnabled">false</property>
    <property name="QueryCacheEnabled">false</property>
    <!-- <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>  -->
    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.infinispan.hibernate.cache.v53.InfinispanRegionFactory</property>
```

hibernate.properties:

```
#logging
hibernate.show_sql = false
hibernate.format_sql = false

#Transaction options
hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class = org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup
hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion = true
hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session = true
jta.UserTransaction = java:jboss/UserTransaction

#JDBC options
hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size = 5
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 0

#caching options
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache = true
hibernate.cache.provider_class = org.infinispan.hibernate.cache.v53.InfinispanRegionFactory
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache = true
hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries = true

#jndi
hibernate.session_factory_name = java:jboss/HibernateFactory
```

Getting

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: HHH025009: Unable to start region factory
        at org.infinispan.hibernate.cache.v53.InfinispanRegionFactory.start(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:248)
        at org.hibernate.cache.internal.EnabledCaching.<init>(EnabledCaching.java:77)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:33)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:24)
        at org.hibernate.service.spi.SessionFactoryServiceInitiator.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceInitiator.java:30)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:68)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
        ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.infinispan.manager.impl.AbstractDelegatingEmbeddedCacheManager.getCacheManagerConfiguration(AbstractDelegatingEmbeddedCacheManager.java:91)
        at org.infinispan.manager.impl.AbstractDelegatingEmbeddedCacheManager.getCacheManagerConfiguration(AbstractDelegatingEmbeddedCacheManager.java:91)
        at org.infinispan.hibernate.cache.v53.InfinispanRegionFactory.defineDataTypeCacheConfigurations(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:393)
        at org.infinispan.hibernate.cache.v53.InfinispanRegionFactory.start(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:242)
        ... 66 more
```

on startup.

Is there anyting else I need to configure to get this running ?

Comment: Looking into this...

Comment: WildFly 13 comes with Hibernate 5.3 and an Infinispan cache provider based on Infinispan 9.2 that works out of the box. There's no need to configure the provider class. Just enable second level cache, see [here](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-simple-tutorials/blob/master/hibernate-cache/wildfly-local/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml). So, please remove `hibernate.cache.provider_class` property.

Comment: Btw, I have updated our simple Hibernate and Infinispan cache tutorial in [this branch](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-simple-tutorials/tree/wf13_hbcache/hibernate-cache/wildfly-local) to use WildFly 13 and works fine. No need to touch with the provider class.